# Change the default build template for TFS builds

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Recently we upgraded from TFS2010 to TFS2013, which added a new build template default that we wish to use for all builds. However, the default being provided when we select "Default Template" is the old TFS2010 build template.

How do I change the file that is used as the 'default template' in TFS builds?

Note that I do not want to *customize* the template, I want to change which file is used for "default".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this in TFS2013 or VS2013. You must use an external tool.

@DaveShaw came close with his suggestion to use TFS Team Project Manager, which ended up solving the issue.

TFS TPM has the ability to [register specific files](https://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com/documentation#Build%20Process%20Templates) as the 'default' and 'upgrade' templates, as well as unregistering old unused templates. This worked very well and our updated build process template file is now set as the default.

Answer (score 2):

The default build template when creating a new Build Definition is the first one when ordered alphabetically.

You cannot select a template to be the default.

What you can do is either:

1. Unregistrer the old template using [TFS Team Project Manager](https://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com/).
2. Rename your preferred template to appear before "Default.xaml"

Comment: @MrDoom I've re-written my answer based on your comment.

Comment: This got me the rest of the way there. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it does, can't believe I forgot that :o